# Meteor template to pdf

Tags: meteor

Is it possible to convert one of my meteor templates to a pdf file?  ie. build a template and then within meteor code point to it and save as a file/data maintaining the formatting and style etc.

I have had a look at pdfkit but as far as I can tell this requires manually building the pdf in code.

Comment: The best thing I know is [jsPDF](http://parall.ax/products/jspdf), although their HTML renderer is marked with "early stages" label for over a year.

Comment: That's very close to what I need but unfortunately it only scrapes text. I need to keep my page formatting in terms of tables, borders, images etc.

Comment: @A_L you could use `spiderable`/`phantomjs` to render your pages to `wkhtml2pdf` to directly change your rendered html page to a pdf

Comment: I also have this need. If anyone reading this has actually built a solution to achieve this, can you please post an answer outlining what you used and how you did it? Or even post a simple project on Github? Thanks!

Comment: @Akshat I installed wkhtmltopdf on my meteor server and I am able to generate pdf's from URL using the command line but I don't knowhow to do this from within meteor - do you have any pointers?

Comment: @A_L, did you ever find a solution? I suspect that server side rendering is the necessary ingredient. I am looking to do exactly what you have described.

Answer (score 1):

Try [phantomjs](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-phantom). Follow their [rasterize example](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js) to generate the pdf. You should load this library only on the server side as it's a big one.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
if(Meteor.is_server) {
  var exec;
  var file = "myPdf.pdf";
  var cmd = "wkhtmltopdf2 -q /tmp/" + file + ".html /tmp/" + file + ".pdf";

  Meteor.startup(function() {
    exec = __meteor_bootstrap__.require('child_process').exec;
  });

  exec(cmd, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout ? stdout : stderr);
  }); 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for Javascript heavy sites like Meteor. wkhtmltopdf doesn't have browser like environment to load the data on the client side.